# Persisting large array for faster access

Tags: java

I have a 5 dimensional array, where all indicies range from 2-14. It contains all the possible permutations of a 5 number sequence.
This array holds 525720 permutations, which takes quite a while to compute. (5-7 seconds on my Macbook pro). It should be used as a lookup table, to access a value in constant time, or more specific, the value of a certain poker-hand:

```
array[2][3][4][5][7] // 1
array[5][5][5][5][14] // 2000
```

Is there a faster way to create this array? I was thinking about persisting the array in some way, and then load it each time my program starts - but is there any efficient ways to do this?

I'm not very familiar with persistence. I dont really know if it's worth it for me, to load it from disk, instead of create it each time. I know about Hibernate, but this seems like a bit of a overkill, just to persist a single array?

Comment: how are you handling suits? 2/3/4/5/7 could be a flush, in which case it would presumably have a better score than 1

Comment: Presumably he is checking the suits separately, to cut the size of the array down significantly.  It could be cut down even more by noting that the order of the cards does not matter (`array[2][3][4][5][6]` is the same as `array[4][2][5][6][3]`), and that some hands are impossible (`array[3][3][3][3][3]`)

Comment: @BlueRaja - If he is using table look-up for performance reasons, you *would* have to store `array[2][3][4]p[5][6]` in addition to `array[4][2][5][6][3]`. I've tried this. You don't have time to sort the cards before doing the array look-up. Sorting the cards is ***way*** slower than just doing the calculation so, unfortunately, to get a performance improvement, you have to store all permutations of the hand.

Comment: I was first planning to sort the cards at run-time actually. But when I realized how many times this should be done, I figured that the fastest way was to compute all the permutations.

Comment: @Robert C. Cartaino:  You have to sort them (a whole 10 operations) to check for a straight, so it cannot be *"way slower"* than doing the calculation... anyways, my point was that it drastically reduces the size of the array (by a factor of around 100)

Comment: *"(a whole 10 operations)"* Remember, that's **per hand**. When you're evaluating 10's-of-millions of hands per second, that's pretty significant. Sorting slowed down my poker evaluator by a factor of four **(!)**. When *space* is more important than *performance*, sorting is fine. But performance was more important for fast evaluations. Doing a table look-up on array[2][3][4][5][6] (straight) is just as fast as array[4][3][2][5][6] (straight). You don't *have* to sort them.

Comment: With this solution: suffecool.net/poker/evaluator.html (The link you posted yesterday Robert), we dont need to worry about large arrays, or sorting. It's just brilliant!

Comment: @Frederik Wordenskjold - Yes, brilliant. Glad you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do, if the computation of the array is too expensive, is serialize it.  That basically places a binary copy of the data onto a storage medium (e.g. your hard disk) that you can very quickly load.

Serialization is pretty straightforward.  Here's [a tutorial](http://www.java-tips.org/blog/java-se/serializing-arrays.html) that specifically addresses serializing arrays.

Since these values will presumably only change if your algorithm for evaluating a poker hand changes, it should be fine to just ship the serialized file.  The file size should be reasonable if the data you are storing in each array element is not too large (if it's a 16-bit integer for example, the file will be around 1MB in size).

Comment: the serialized file will also compress very well.. probably > 90% compression ratio

Comment: Depends in the distribution of values within the array, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Write it out via MappedByteBuffer. Create a big enough file, map it, get an asIntBuffer(), put in your numbers.

Then you can map it later and access it via IntBuffer.get(obvious-math-on-indices).

This is much faster the serialization.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by collapsing your dimensions for indexing:

assuming you have a set of indexes (from your first example, allowed values are 2 to 14):

```
 i1 = 2
 i2 = 3
 i3 = 5
 i4 = 6
 i5 = 7
```

and created your array with

```
 short array[] = new short[13 * 13 * 13 * 13 * 13];
 ...
```

then accessing each element becomes

```
 array[(i1 - 2) * 13 * 13 * 13 * 13 + (i2 - 2) * 13 * 13 * 13 + (i3 - 2)
     * 13 * 13 + (i4 - 2) * 13 + (i5 - 2)]
```

This array will take much less memory since you don't need to create an additional layer of objects along each dimension, and you can easily store the entire contents in a file and load it in one list.

It will also be faster to traverse this array because you will be doing 1/5 the array lookups.

Also the tightening up of the number of elements in each dimension will save significant memory.

To keep your code clean this array should be hidden inside an object with a get and set method which takes the five indexes.

Comment: +1 also make sure to use `short` rather than `int` to cut the memory usage in half - 1MB is really not that much to worry about persisting to disk.  Also, 2-14 is 13 numbers, not 12 :)

Comment: Interesting! I'll definitely look into this!

Comment: It might be true, but I doubt that "It will also be faster to traverse this array because you will be doing 1/5 the array lookups." since array index calculation is essentially mult + add etc. under the hood...

Comment: @harschware:  actually, that's not true.  Java does not really support multidimensional arrays - the original syntax is actually an array of arrays (of arrays, of arrays...).  These are called *ragged arrays* - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Efficiency (under *"An alternative to multidimensional arrays..."*).  Thus, looking up a single element requires five-array lookups.

Answer (score 2):

*Not a direct answer to your original question, but...*

If you are trying to do fast poker-hand evaluations, you want to make sure you read through [The Great Poker Hand Evaluator Roundup](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup).

Particularly: [Cactus Kev's Poker Hand Evaluator](http://www.suffecool.net/poker/evaluator.html).

I was involved in long-running discussion about running the fastest possible 5- and 7-hand poker evaluations where most of this stuff comes from. Frankly, I don't see how these evaluations are going to any faster until you can hold all C(52,5) or 2,598,960 hand values in a look-up table.

Comment: I've read the first article, which is very interesting, and useful. I'll read the second one through.

I guess this in interesting, when also considering the suits.

Ohh, and I've just taken over for my friend, who posted the original question, and created an actual user with this name. Just to clear out any name confusion.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*I'm not convinced that your number-of-poker-hand permutations is correct but, in any case...*</sup>

You can make your array initialization **approximately 120-times faster** by storing every permutation of a given poker hand at once. That works because the "value" of a poker hand is not affected by the order of the cards.

First calculate the value for the a hand. Say you have five cards (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5):

```
handValue = EvaluateHand(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5);

// Store the pre-calculated hand value in a table for faster lookup
hand[c1][c2][c3][c4][c5] = handValue;
```

Then assign the handValue to *all* permutations of that hand (i.e. the *order* of the cards doesn't change the handValue).

```
hand[c1][c2][c3][c5][c4] = handValue;
hand[c1][c2][c4][c3][c5] = handValue;
hand[c1][c2][c4][c5][c3] = handValue;
hand[c1][c2][c5][c3][c4] = handValue;
hand[c1][c2][c5][c4][c3] = handValue;
:
etc.
:
hand[c5][c4][c3][c2][c1] = handValue;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing! Well, actually... I first compute the unique value hands. Then, for each hand, I add its permutations and assign them the same value.

Comment: Ohh, and about the number of permutations.
We have 5 cards, so the number of permutations for 5 different ranked cards is 5! = 120. If we compute this, for say, 1 pair hands, we compute the number of permutations by 120/2! (2! because of the 2 cards with equal rank). Then we multiply this with the number of all  possible 1 pair combinations, which is 2860. When repeated for all hands, I get 525.720 in total. (Of course, disregarding the suits!).

Correct me if I'm wrong. This is obvious important to get right!

Comment: You will definitely enjoy reading this: http://www.suffecool.net/poker/evaluator.html. You are now stumbling into *"a ridiculously freaking clever algorithm for 5-card poker hand recognition."* Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

If this is for poker hands, you can't just store 2-14. You also need to store the suit as well. This really means you need to store 0-51. Otherwise you have no way of knowing if `array[2][3][4][5][6]` is a straight or a straight flush.

If you don't actually need to store the suits for your application, and you really want to do it in an array, use indexes of 0-12, not 2-14. This would allow you to use a 13×13×13×13×13 (371,293 member) array, instead of a 15×15×15×15×15 (759,375 member) array. Whenever you access the array, you'd just need to subtract 2 from each index. (I'm not sure where you got your 525,720 count...)

Comment: @finnw: my bad. 388082 is 15^5 - 13^5. (i.e. the amount of space wasted by using a 15x15 array.) i looked at the wrong number in my calc history. it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for your enthusiasm!

So the straight forward approach seems to just serialize it. I think I'll try this at first, to test the performance, and see if its sufficient. (Which I guess it is).

About the MappedByteBuffer... Is it correctly understood, that this makes it possible to load a fraction of the serialized array? So I load the values I need at run-time, instead of loading the whole array at startup?

@Jennie
The suits are stored in a different array. I'm not sure this is the best way to go, since there's lots of stuff to consider about this particular problem. A flush is basically a high-card hand, with a different value... So There's no real reason for me to store the same permutations (high cards) twice, but this is the way to do it for now. I think the way to go is a hash-function, so I can convert high-card values to flush-values easily, but I have not given this many thoughts.

About the indicies, you're of course right. This is just for now. It's easier for me to test the value for "2 3 4 5 6", by just putting in the card-values for now... Later, I'll cut of the array!